# Depth first search (DFS) in mysql or sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, depth-first-search

I'm looking for a way to implemented depth first search algorithm in mysql or sqlite

the structure of the table is in this format

```
id | node1  | node2 
--------------------
1  |   1    |   1
2  |   1    |   2
3  |   1    |   3
4  |   1    |   4
5  |   2    |   3
6  |   2    |   9
7  |   2    |   8
8  |   2    |   12
9  |   2    |   4
```

This shows the relationships between the node 1 and the nodes thats connected to.

is there any way to implement depth first search (dfs) on it,

thanks for any advice :)

Comment: Search for common table expressions. MySQL has no support for them, but SQLite recently added them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested set or a materialed path model. But sqlite has recursive function.

Comment: yes , i think recursive function in sqlite is what i'm looking for, i work on it now to understand how it work as a depth first search algorithm , thanks for reply :)